# How to find the time difference with respect to date in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to find the time difference between the value in the column of type Date and the fixed time of that particular date.

Consider,

> value in column - 4/16/2011 4:00:19 PM
>
> Fixed time as - 3:00:00 PM

I am expecting the answer as `1hr 0min 19sec ago`.  Whatever the type I'm ok with it.

Thanks

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DateTime` data type.  Do you mean `date`?  Or `timestamp`?  Or something else?  Are you trying to return a string?  Three numeric columns?  Something else?

Comment: And you want a single string returned?  Three numeric columns?  Something else?  What would you want returned if the time in the database was 2:59:59 PM?  Do you want to compare against 3 pm on the previous day?  Do you want the absolute value returned (so 2:59:59 returns the same result as 3:00:01?)?

Comment: I want single string returned.  I have a filter that will filter only the time that is greater than 3:00:00 PM.  So no need to compare with time less than 3PM

Comment: Ahh, so you do care what data type is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't care what data type is returned, I'd probably cast to a `timestamp` so that you can get an `interval day to second` returned.

```
SQL> select cast( sysdate as timestamp ) from dual
  2  ;

CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
15-MAR-15 04.05.46.000000 PM

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select cast( sysdate as timestamp ) -
  2            cast( trunc(sysdate) + interval '15' hour as timestamp )
  3*   from dual
  4  /

CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP)-CAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+INTERVAL'15'HOURASTIMESTAMP)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000000 01:06:18.000000
```

If you want to return a string rather than an interval, you can use `extract` to extract data from the interval

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select extract( hour from delta ) || ' hours, ' ||
  2         extract( minute from delta ) || ' minutes, ' ||
  3         extract( second from delta ) || ' seconds ago'
  4    from (
  5  select cast( sysdate as timestamp ) -
  6            cast( trunc(sysdate) + interval '15' hour as timestamp ) delta
  7    from dual
  8* )
SQL> /

EXTRACT(HOURFROMDELTA)||'HOURS,'||EXTRACT(MINUTEFROMDELTA)||'MINUTES,'||EXTRACT(
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 hours, 10 minutes, 46 seconds ago
```